# Pycharm Packaging error

Tags: python, pycharm, library, package, build-error

Писал бота(discord.py) через repl.it все было хорошо. Но потребовалось перейти на pycharm, прописал в консоли pycharm pip install discord.py. Скопировал рабочий код и:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikita/PycharmProjects/KrBot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/main.py", line 55, in <module>
    bot.run('*.*.*')
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/*/PycharmProjects/*/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

Что не так?

Comment: Ну ругается на неверный ssl сертификат.  Попробуйте запустить код через консоль (без pycharm) возможно дело не в нем. P.S. Последняя поддерживаемая версия python 3.8 если верить https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/

Comment: Правда, дело не в нем. А что не так тогда? не подскажите?

Comment: С discord.py давно очень сталкивался так что в общих чертах... 1. как писал выше у Вас питон 3.9 на сайте прописана поддержка до 3.8 попробуйте на более старой версии. 2. Если не путаю конечно но вроде была проблема с сертификатами под Windows. Решалось запуском под  linux. Более конкретно может кто еще дополнит ну или гугл с яндексом )

Comment: `/Applications/Python 3.9/Install Certificates.command` должно помочь. Рядом лежит `ReadMe.rtf` с дополнительной информацией.

Comment: @Kers А не подскажите как создать 3.8 проект на pycharm

Comment: Ураа! Спасибо всем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла установка версии Python 3.8 и перевод программы на файл питона 3.8